# Select only one row from a join based on foreign condition

Tags: mysql, join

## The main idea

- user `hasMany` roles (data is stored in the tables: `users`, `roles`, `user_role`)
- i want to know if the **user is admin OR client**
- this data will then be `join`ed to a different result

## What I'm doing

```sql
SELECT
  `users`.`id`,
  `users`.`name`,
  `roles`.`display_name`
FROM `users`
  JOIN role_user ON users.id = role_user.user_id
  JOIN roles ON role_user.role_id = roles.id
```

## Why it's wrong

Because this is the result I get

```sql
id       Name    Display name

1       admin    Admin
1       admin    Client
2       admin2   Admin
2       admin2   Client
3       client   Client
7       test     Admin
7       test     Client
```

## What I want

```sql
id       Name   Display name

1       admin   Admin
2       admin2  Admin
3       client  Client
7       test    Admin
```

## How I'm working to make this work

- Using aggregates somehow
- Using cases somehow
- Joining with a subset of the data somehow

Thank you for your idea !

[Update] Here is an [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/599d0/4/0) describing the issue.

Comment: please make an SQL fiddle. We need to understand your data and table structures.

Comment: Your role_user table have the issue. Why are you inserting 2 rows for the same user_id? 1 for Admin and 1 for Client. Remove either of them and you will get your result.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query :

```
SELECT users.`id`, users.`name`, MIN(roles.`display_name`)
FROM `users` users, `role_user` role_user, `roles` roles
WHERE users.id = role_user.user_id AND role_user.role_id = roles.id
GROUP BY users.`id`
```

In your query you join tables which give you all possible combinations of results. This query will select only the role_user/roles for each found userId.

EDIT : added "group by" to select only unique users and "min" to select its alphabetically lowest role (so "admin" get selected before "client")

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue, since data is still duplicated in the result.

I need to get only one result for the user role in the following way:

If the user is admin and client I want admin.
If the user is admin I want admin.
If the user is client I want client.

Comment: Some changes : I added MIN() to select the alphabetically lowest value : so he will chose ADMIN before CLIENT if both are present. I also added a "GROUP BY" because we want only to display each user once.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
      `users`.`id`,
      `users`.`name`,
      `roles`.`display_name`
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN (select user_id,min(role_id)role_id from role_user group by user_id) role_user ON users.id = role_user.user_id
left JOIN roles ON role_user.role_id = roles.id
```

Comment: till getting issue please check ids

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work fine for you:

```
select * from users
where users.id in (
select users.id FROM users
  JOIN role_user ON (users.id = role_user.user_id)
  JOIN roles ON (role_user.role_id = roles.id)
  where roles.display_name like 'admin'
)
Union
select * from users
where users.id not in (
select users.id FROM users
  JOIN role_user ON (users.id = role_user.user_id)
  JOIN roles ON (role_user.role_id = roles.id)
  where roles.display_name like 'admin'
);
```

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fabba/42

I would recommend to create a view for the sub-query, but I couldn't do it on fiddle.

Example using a view:

```
Create or replace view admin_list as
  select users.id FROM users
  JOIN role_user ON (users.id = role_user.user_id)
  JOIN roles ON (role_user.role_id = roles.id)
  where roles.display_name like 'admin';
```

Then the query will be much compact:

```
select * from users
where users.id in (
  select users.id FROM admin_list
)
Union
select * from users
where users.id not in (
  select users.id FROM admin_list
);
```

Answer (score 0):

My own solution was the following

- create a view to get the user's role id (either admin or client)
- join with the view

Specifically here is the view

```sql
CREATE VIEW vw_users_role_by_priority AS (
  SELECT
    role_user.user_id,
    min(role_user.role_id) AS 'role_id'
  FROM role_user
    JOIN roles ON role_user.role_id = roles.id
  GROUP BY role_user.user_id
);
```

And here is the final query

```
SELECT
  `users`.`id`,
  `roles`.display_name
FROM `users`
  JOIN vw_users_role_by_priority  ON vw_users_role_by_priority.user_id = users.id
  JOIN roles ON roles.id = vw_users_role_by_priority.role_id
ORDER BY `users`.`name` ASC;
```